# Настройка веб сервера

Tags: debian

Ребята, привет :) Стало мне мало виртуального хостинга, решил переехать.

Есть VDS с минимальным дистрибутивом Debian 6, нужно сделать из него веб-сервер. Опыта конечно же, нет. Точнее, нет его без панели управления. ISPManager на сервере отсутствует. Установил пакеты aptitude\php\mysql и иже с ними. За основу вебсервера было решено взять **Cherokee**. К этим вещам нареканий нет, всё работает.

Но теперь возникло абсолютное непонимание того, как создавать директории с сайтами, переносить домены. С доменами особенное непонимание, ситуация усугубляется плохим знанием английского.

Пожалуйста, помогите или посоветуйте годную статью, как это дело до конца допилить.

С уважением

Comment: Все проблемы решены, поставил апач :)

Answer (score 1):

> Все проблемы решены, поставил апач :)

Apache лучше спрятать за nginx (или вовсе заменить на nginx). Голый апач в интернет лучше не выставлять, уж больно он прожорлив и уязвим к DoSу (наиболее выразительный пример — Slow post/get атака, один комп с медленным соединением может «отключить» сервер с нормальным каналом)